# TypeScript: how do I initialize an object and give some default values from its type

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an interface called `Obj` and it contains a bunch of `boolean`

```
interface Obj {
  isVisited: boolean,
  isChecked: boolean,
  isToggled: boolean
}
```

And I want to initialize an object of this type and assign every property of it with `false`

```
const obj: Obj = {
  isVisited: false,
  isChecked: false,
  isToggled: false
}
```

I wonder is there a programmatic way of doing it rather than manually tying it out?

Comment: you could declare it as a class and assign properties in constructor

Answer (score 2):

You can create a class which implement `Obj` interface with default value for the properties.

```
class ObjClass implements Obj {
  isVisited: boolean = false;
  isChecked: boolean = false;
  isToggled: boolean = false;
}

const obj = new ObjClass();
```

Now, `obj` has 3 attributes and default values are `false`.

Or, try keep it simple, you can create a `factory` function to create default object.

```
function genObjDefault(): Obj {
  return {
    isVisited: false,
    isChecked: false,
    isToggled: false
  }
}

const obj = genObjDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd go the other way around: instantiate an object, then take the type from the object:

```
const obj = {
  isVisited: false,
  isChecked: false,
  isToggled: false
}
type Obj = typeof obj;
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you cannot have a default initialization for interfaces, but you can create a class with default values like below.

```
class TestA {
    private label = "";
    protected value = 0;
    public list: string[] = null;
}
```

Emitted javascript would be

```
var TestA = /** @class */ (function () {
    function TestA() {
        this.label = "";
        this.value = 0;
        this.list = null;
    }
    return TestA;
}());
```